# What happened to GridFS?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, gridfs

I'm just porting an application over to use the new [version 2.0 MongoDB C# driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver). I'm struggling replacing the parts that use the GridFS as I wasn't able to find any news or documentation regarding GridFS. Since it's class is marked as deprecated: how to use this in the latest version?

Sample code that's failing:

```
// read and store local file in database
using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
{
  // generate unique file name and upload it
  var remoteFile = DbCurrent.GridFS.Upload(stream, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
  // save file id
  _currentAttachment.FileId = remoteFile.Id.AsObjectId;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, GridFS is not available with the async 2.0.0 driver yet, see [CSHARP-1191](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1191). It appears they're currently working on it.

Comment: I see, that's great news! So I'll just wait 'till they announce it, thank you!

Comment: @Nefarius This is fixed in the 2.1 release of the driver which is now available.